# Architecture of the Audience Compilation?

Tags: 2007, administration, audience-targeting, user-profile, architecture

I went through the SharePoint Escalation team blogs and understood the basic architecture of the "User Profile Import" and still would like to know the architecture of the "Audience Compilation" and how it uses "User Profile Import" ?

Help me with thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global audiences are created by utilizing the user profile information that is imported into user profiles. An administrator will create an audience rule or rules that will review the profiles currently imported by the user profile import and either include the person in the audience or remove them from the audience based on whether or not they meet the conditions within the rule. This is why audiencing is not security. It does not grant or deny permissions to any objects as the audience is only as accurate as the most recent profile import.

Comment: What will happen if we compile the audience hourly basis ? will it cause any performance issue ?